# How to compare two json object if matches return those values?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two json data object as below:

```
const currentUser = {"subAccount":{"setup":true, "edit": true, "delete": true}};
const parentUser = {"subAccount":{"setup":true, "edit": true}, "game": {"edit"}};
```

I want to compare between two json data if object inside is matches.

**Expected data:**

```
{
  "subAccount": {
     "setup": true,
     "edit": true
   }
}
```

Please help me out thank before hand.

Comment: Hey, will your two objects will always have the same level of nesting? If yes then you can iterate over object keys and create new object using reduce function.

Comment: There isn't any JSON in your question. [JSON](https://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure, usually an object or an array. Both `currentUser` and `parentUser` are JavaScript objects and nothing more. They do not need quotes around property names (the quotes are required when the property names do not follow the rules of the JS variable names). Adding quotes around property names do not make it JSON.

Comment: Thank you @aditya81070. No it's not sir.

Comment: @ChantySok If the objects have arbitrary depth then I would suggest writing a recursive function that will compare one object level with the second object's every level. For example `{ a: 'b', c: { d: 'f'}}` and `{a: { e: { d: 'f'}}`, will compare `a` with deep nested object.

Comment: @aditya81070 Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const main = () => {
  const currentUser = {
    subAccount: {
      setup: true,
      edit: true,
      delete: true
    },
  };
  
  const parentUser = {
    subAccount: {
      setup: true,
      edit: true,
    },
    game: {
      edit: true
    }
  }
  const result = compareTwoObj(currentUser, parentUser);
  // print the result;
  console.log('result====>', JSON.stringify(result));
}


const compareTwoObj = (obj1, obj2) => {
  const common = {};
  for (const key of Object.keys(obj2)) {
      if (obj2[key] !== undefined) {
          if (typeof obj1[key] === 'object') {
              common[key] = compareTwoObj(obj1[key], obj2[key]);
          }
          else {
              if (obj1[key] === obj2[key]) {
                  common[key] = obj1[key];
              }
          }
      }
  }
  return common;
}

main();
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. It pretty good. But, When I added it to my code. it show error **eslint** with message **no-restricted-syntax iterators/generators**

Comment: maybe it's giving you an error due to ForOfStatement, so you can change from  ForOfStatement to ForLoop statement

Answer (score 0):

I will write a recursive function like this.

```
function compare(current, parent) {
    let result = {};
    for (let key of Object.keys(parent)) {
        if (parent[key] != undefined) {
            if (typeof current[key] == "object") {
                result[key] = compare(current[key], parent[key]);
            }
            else {
                if (current[key] == parent[key]) {
                    result[key] = current[key];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```